# Label not displaying converted decimal number

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, label

I have an ICollection of objects each containing a premium property of type decimal. In my view I have the following code where a table is populated with the premium properties

```
 @foreach (var section in Model.PolicySectionCollection)
 {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.Label(section.Premium.ToString())
            </td>
        </tr>
 }
```

Inspecting

```
section.Premium.ToString()
```

using a quick view, reveals that the value is for example "12500.00"

Inspecting

```
@Html.Label(section.Premium.ToString())
```

using a quick view, reveals that the generated code is

```
<label for="">00</label>
```

So all my decimal numbers is displayed as 00. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: I believe that the argument is being treated as the property.  So, with a property of "12500.00" it's taking the name "00" which is not correct. Try @Html.Raw instead

Comment: Thank you @PugFugly, that worked 100%, this problem was frustrating me for the last 2 hours. If you want to post your comments as an answer I will mark it as correct for you. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Html.Label
```

will produce a label for a provided property.  In your case you're passing in a value as the property name.  So it's treating "12500.00" as the name of a property you want to display.  Of course that's not what you're intending to do, you simple want to display the value of a given property.

Try

```
@Html.Raw
```

.. instead.  All you want to do is print the actual value which @Html.Raw will do for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.Label(Convert.ToInt32(section.Premium).ToString())
```

Or for decimal Value

```
 <label for=''> @section.Premium</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

While @Html.Raw() will work, the result will no longer be a label, which can mess with formatting if you've applied specific styling to labels. Fortunately, @Html.Label() won't attempt the property-reading behavior [if you provide it a separate labelText parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.label#System_Web_Mvc_Html_LabelExtensions_Label_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_String_), so just pass in the same variable twice.

```
@Html.Label(section.Premium.ToString(), section.Premium.ToString())
```